# One of my childviews doesn't react on anything

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got 2 childview controllers added to my controller.

They both fill the screen for the half. Now my tableview I can use, I can scroll, click everything works.

My map is there, but I can't scroll or use it.

I tested the map before adding it as childview controller. I could scroll and use it.

This is how I added the 2 view controllers:

```
-(void) initView
{
    [self initMapView];
    [self initPOITableView];
}

-(void) initMapView
{
    _mapView = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:_mapView];
    _mapView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width , -self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
    [self.view addSubview:_mapView.view];
    [_mapView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

-(void) initPOITableView
{
    _poiTableView = [[POITableViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:_poiTableView];
    _poiTableView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:_poiTableView.view];
    [_poiTableView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: Is that a typo, or the height of the mapView is negative? (-self.view.bounds.size.height / 2)

Comment: iOS sorry forgot the tag.

Comment: Nvm. That fixed it. Leaving the - away. But before I added the other childview it really filled up the screen.. Weird. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: If you're talking about mapView, I don't know why it's filling up the screen. According to the frame settings, it should exactly fill the half of the screen. But I'm suspicious about TableView, since its height is the same with the superview's height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like EDUsta pointed. Removing the - so the height isn't negative fixed the problem.

```
   -(void) initMapView
    {
        _mapView = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
        [self addChildViewController:_mapView];
        _mapView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width , self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
        [self.view addSubview:_mapView.view];
        [_mapView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
```